# Postgres - Create index for full text search using 3 + columns with to_tsvector

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, database-indexes

All of the examples in Postgres full text search documentation show creating an index by concatenating 2 columns, but I cannot solve how to do this with 3+ columns. Example from the Postgres docs:

```
to_tsvector(title || ' ' || body)
```

If I for example have another column that should be searched through called `description`, it seems that this syntax does not work as I expect:

```
to_tsvector(title || ' ' || body || ' ' || description)
```

It results in an index like this when I try it:

```
to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, ((("CompanyName" || ' '::text) || "Title") || ' '::text) || "Description")
```

There seems to be an extra set of parantheses wrapping the `CompanyName` and `Title` block.

Any ideas on what the syntax should be here? I'm having trouble finding any relevant documentation on using more columns with `to_tsvector`.

Comment: Closely related, on dba.SE: [PostgreSQL full text search on many columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/164081/3684)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index is quite good and will be used whenever you use the same expression in a query.

Indexed expressions are not stored as text, but as a parsed tree structure. That way it doesn't break the index if you for example rename a used column.

The string concatenation operator `||` is left associative, so the parenthesized expression is identical to the one you originally wrote (with the exception of the configuration `english` that is required to make the expression `IMMUTABLE`, but I guess you just forgot that).